# Error in R: Unused arguments: Error in SN(0.1, 0, 1, 0.4, 0) : unused arguments (0.4, 0)

Tags: r, function

I have following code:

```
SN<- function(n) {
  SE<-0
  for(i in 1:n){
    if(i==1){
      SE<- x[i]*(1/t*(1-exp(-x[n+1]*t)))
    }
    if(i!=1){
      SE<-x[i+1]*(SE*i-(((x[n+1]*t)^(i)*exp(-x[n+1]*t))/(x[n+1])))
    }
  }
  SE<-x[n+2]+(1/t)*SE
  return(SE)
} 

SN(c(0.1,0,1),0.4,1)
```

My goal was to set x[0]=0.1, x[1]=0, x[2]=1, t=0.4 and n=1

But i got error: Error in SN(0.1, 0, 1, 0.4, 0) : unused arguments (0.4, 0)

I know that there is a mistake that argument used does not match the arguments in the argument list. But in my case I do not know how to fix it.

Any help?

Comment: Use `c`: `SN(c(0.1,0,1),0.4,0)`.

Comment: There are two problems that are immediately clear.  First, your argument for `x` would have to be a vector, `SN(c(0.1, 0,1), .4, 0)`. The other is internal to the function, you can't use an index of 0, vector's in R are indexed with the first value as 1.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong I updated my code, can you check? but it still does not work

Comment: @Maël it still does not work

Comment: @Cherry can you tell us what you're trying to do with this function? We might be able to troubleshoot it a bit better in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This produces an answer.  You'll have to make sure it's the answer you think it should be:

```r
  SN<- function(x,t,n) {
  SE<-0
  for(i in 1:n){
    if(i==1){
      SE<- x[i]*(1/t*(1-exp(-x[n+1]*t)))
    }
    if(i!=1){
      SE<-x[i+1]*(SE*i-(((x[n+1]*t)^(i)*exp(-x[n+1]*t))/(x[n+1])))
    }
  }
  SE<-x[n+2]+(1/t)*SE
  return(SE)
} 

SN(c(0.1,0,1),0.4,1)
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>